# For a shopping cart which would you use to set cookies (PHP or JavaScript)?

Tags: php, javascript, shopping-cart

I'm building a cookie based shopping cart, I'm not sure if I should be using JavaScript or PHP for setting the cookies. Which would you use JS or whatever server side language you are using on the same project and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use what was appropriate for the specific situation.

Making a round trip to the server to set a cookie seems silly, and sending JS to the client to set a cookie the server generated also seems out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

PHP, because the user might not have JavaScript (enabled). Optional JavaScript usage would be a bonus for users with enabled JavaScript, though.